# Angular 2: onChanges() is not reflecting Object value changes

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

`preDefinedSearch` is object

`searchCategory` is string,

when I change both values, at very first event of `OnChanges`contains both value like below,

`Changes:  Object {searchCategory: SimpleChange, preDefinedSearch: SimpleChange}`

but with next update to the both property is not reflecting, contains only string value as changed value after first event of `OnChnages`.

`Changes:  Object {searchCategory: SimpleChange}`

Below is `ngOnChanges` implementation:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}): void {
console.log("Changes: ", changes);
if (this.searchForm) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    if (propName === "preDefinedSearch") {
      console.log("preDefinedSearch from inside: ", changes[propName]);
    }
    if(propName === "searchCategory") {
      console.log("searchCategory from inside: ", changes[propName].currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Provided solution didn't work?

Comment: I meant 
`Changes:  Object {searchCategory: SimpleChange, preDefinedSearch: SimpleChange}`
and 
`Changes:  Object {searchCategory: SimpleChange}`

There is not `preDefinedSearch` in  second `Changes Object`. so I am not sure if I can access it through your solution. and I guess by mistake I deleted your previous comments.

Comment: Got it:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Objects are mutable so onChanges is not detecting any changes. so need to use immutable objects.